# de-structuring to obtain results property of the parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Create a displayCartTotal function. It should expect a parameter and should use object de-structuring to obtain results property of the parameter. This function will be called with the data from an API call and it will display the total payment bill.
i try doing this but not working

```
const displayCartTotal=({result})=>{
    return result

 };
```

Comment: So what does object being passed in look like? Your instructions say to look for `results` property but your destructuring is `result` instead. Always provide a [mcve]

Comment: *obtain **results** property of the parameter* but you've used `result`

Answer (score 1):

You need to some read about object desctruxt
You write ({ result }) it’s equivalent of (data) => {var result = data.result}